# What is the difference between p2p file system and distributed file system?

Tags: distributed, p2p, distributed-system

When I googled for a distributed storage tool for my app,
I found two type of technologies: 
The first represent themselves as p2p file system (IPFS..)
 and the others as distributed files system (Ceph ..) 
so what is the different between p2p systems and distributed system ?

what I believe (it can be wrong) is that p2p systems doesn't assume trust between nodes, in contrast distributed systems all nodes have to trust each others or at least trust a "master" node.

Answer (score 1):

P2P is a Distributed System Architecture.

> what I believe (it can be wrong) is that p2p systems doesn't assume
>   trust between nodes, in contrast distributed systems all nodes have to
>   trust each others or at least trust a "master" node.

It depends on your definition of trust. If the 'trust' means standalone computer node operation,  then you are correct.

P2P involves a component called Peer. In P2P, each peer has the same power/capability with another peer in the network. One peer can work alone without another peer.

Another example of Distributed System Architecture is Client-Server Architecture.

The client has a limited capability compared to peer. The client must connect to Server to perform a specific task. The client has limited capability without a server.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed files system (DFS) combine several nodes storage (can be a large number) in a way that end user this see as single storage space. There is middleware that manage with all disks space and take care of data. Now, this Distributed file system can relay on servers or can relay on simple workstations. If nodes are Workstation we are talking about P2P DF system and if there are servers then we just say distributed file systems. I have to say that even P2P file system could involve node that act as server for indexing files, maping locatione etc.P2P DFS is effected by churn nature of peers (join/leave behaviour), while server based don t have this problem.

The best approach is to analyze several P2P distributed file Systems like Freenet, CFS, Oceanstores (interesanting since it use untrusted servers that act as peers), Farsite etc. take a look [here](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs5204/fall08-kafura/Papers/FileSystems/Survey.pdf) for more.
And some DFS like Cepth, Hadoop, Riak etc ... some of them you can find [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277935726_A_Survey_on_Distributed_File_System_Technology)

Hope this helped.